# facebook integration in android app

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   // FACEBOOK INTEGRATION INITIALIZATION
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginButton fbLoginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager= CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fbLoginButton=(LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);


 //FACEBOOK FUNCTION FOR LOGIN

        fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                System.out.println("Facebook Login Successful!");
                System.out.println("Logged in user Details : ");
                System.out.println("--------------------------");
                System.out.println("User ID  : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
                System.out.println("Authentication Token : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login cancelled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Facebook Login failed!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login unsuccessful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Facebook Login failed!!");
            }
        });



//INITIALIZATION OF BUTTONS
        Button button;
        final EditText edit_name,edit_pass,edit_email,edit_phone;
        final CheckBox check;
        SharedPreferences pref;
         final Editor editor;

//INSTANCES
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        edit_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        edit_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_pass);
        edit_email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
        edit_phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_phone);
        check=(CheckBox)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        pref=getSharedPreferences("Registration",0);
        editor=pref.edit();

//CHECKBOX FUNTION

       check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if(!check.isChecked())
               {
                   edit_pass.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
               }
               else
               {
                   edit_pass.setTransformationMethod(null);
               }
           }
       });


//BUTTONS

               button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       boolean flag =true;
                       String name=edit_name.getText().toString();
                       String email=edit_email.getText().toString();
                       String pass=edit_pass.getText().toString();
                       String phone=edit_phone.getText().toString();


                       if(!isValidEmail(email))
                        {
                           edit_email.setError("Invalid Email");
                           flag=false;
                        }
                       if(!isValidPassword(pass))
                       {
                           edit_pass.setError("Invalid Password");
                           flag=false;
                       }
                       if (!isValidPhone(phone))
                       {
                           edit_phone.setError("Invalid phone");
                           flag=false;
                       }



                       if(flag==true)
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           editor.putString("Name", name);
                           editor.putString("Email", email);
                           editor.putString("phone",phone);
                           editor.putString("password",pass);
                           editor.commit();
                           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,upload_photo.class);
                           startActivity(i);

                       }
                       else
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LOGIN UNSUCCESSFUL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }
               });

    }

//FUNCTIONS

    private boolean isValidEmail(String email)
    {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+ "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    private boolean isValidPassword(String password)
    {
        if(password!=null && password.length()>6)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    private boolean isValidPhone(String phone)
    {
        if (phone.length()==10)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent i) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, i);
    }    
}
```

this is working fine on emulator, but fb login is not working on phone with facebook app in it ,i read somewhere that i need to use   facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, this);
    but dont know where to use that , can you please help me in that???

Comment: if your hash key is not set properly than also you can run application successfully in mobile which has no facebook app installed.  But you get problem in device which has already fb app installed. check it.

Answer (score 0):

use this code it's works with already installed facebook application.

```html
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
 "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

  System.out.println("onSuccess");

  String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
   .getToken();
  Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  loginResult.getAccessToken(),
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
   public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
   GraphResponse response) {

    Log.i("LoginActivity",
    response.toString());
    try {
     String id = object.getString("id");
     try {
      URL profile_pic = new URL(
       "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
      Log.i("profile_pic",
      profile_pic + "");

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     String name = object.getString("name");
     String email = object.getString("email");
     String gender = object.getString("gender");
     String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields",
   "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
  System.out.println("onCancel");
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
  System.out.println("onError");
  Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
 }
});
```

```html
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
 callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
}
```